# Convert written time to text (timestamp)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task to write a macro that will replace the given time with text into a number representing the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds in Excel.

Example data
Text -> Expected result

| Text | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 22 min | 00:00:22:00 |
| 1 h, 5 min | 00:01:05:00 |
| 2 days, 15 h, 4 min | 02:15:04:00 |
| 1 day, 15 min | 01:00:15:00 |
| 2 weeks, 5 days, 5 min | 19:00:05:00 |

I tried to do it with a lot of ifs but it doesn't seem like a good solution, anyone else have an idea?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes, there is a mistake, I have already corrected it. Thanks for the answer, will try to implement it

Answer (score 4):

if you use vba then this function would solve your problem

```
Function str2time(ByVal tmpstr As String)
On Error GoTo exit_Function
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Split(tmpstr, ",")
Dim I As Long
Dim d As Long: d = 0
Dim h As Long: h = 0
Dim m As Long: m = 0
      For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(LCase(arr(I)), "week") > 0 Then
            d = d + Val(arr(I)) * 7
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(arr(I)), "day") > 0 Then
            d = d + Val(arr(I))
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(arr(I)), "h") > 0 Then
            h = Val(arr(I))
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(arr(I)), "min") > 0 Then
            m = Val(arr(I))
            End If
      Next I
str2time = IIf(d > 10, d, "0" & d) & ":" & IIf(h > 10, h, "0" & h) & ":" & IIf(m > 10, m, "0" & m) & ":00"
exit_Function:
End Function
```

very simple and self explaind